# Declare function from within dictionary

Tags: python

```
def mainProgram(myDict):
    methodDict = {'add': addDB(myDict, params[1], params[2]),
                  'find': findDB(myDict, params[1]),
                  'del': removeDB(myDict, params[1], params[2]),
                  'clear': clearAll(myDict)}
    inpt = None
    while inpt != "End":
        inpt = input("-->")
        params = inpt.split()
        methodDict[params[0]]
```

Here is my code, when I try to execute the code I get, "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'params' referenced before assignment"

Is it possible to do what I am trying to do in python?

Comment: Pls first correct your function indentation.

Comment: @Kasra There we go. Must have copy and pasted weird.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? what is possible input/output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, what actually happens at

```
 methodDict = {'add': addDB(myDict, params[1], params[2]),
              'find': findDB(myDict, params[1]),
              'del': removeDB(myDict, params[1], params[2]),
              'clear': clearAll(myDict)}
```

is that you **execute** `addDB` etc, that is, your methodDict would contain the result of `addDB(...params...)` if it were to run.

Unfortunately it does not run, as params is not defined when that execution happens.

What you'd want to do is, store a callable in the dictionary and run it... something like

```
methodDict = {'add': lambda x: addDB(myDict, x[0], x[1])}
# and you execute with
methodDict['add'](params)
```

Comment: it seems silly to compose this function. See my answer

Comment: @AdamSmith I agree. I just wanted to show that you have to have a callable there without altering the code that much. In fact, yours is cleaner and much more "proper". I upvoted it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) function to delay the execution of a function unless all parameters are provided.

```
from functools import partial

def add(x, y):
    return x + y

>>> partial_add = partial(add, 5)
>>> partial_add(7)
12
```

---

As for your question;

```
def mainProgram(myDict):
    methodDict = {'add': partial(addDB, myDict),
                  'find': partial(findDB, myDict),
                  'del': partial(removeDB, myDict),
                  'clear': partial(clearAll, myDict)}

    inpt = None
    while inpt != "End":
        inpt = input("-->")
        params = inpt.split()
        methodDict[params[0]](*params[1:])
```

Comment: consider breaking up the `inpt.split` using tuple unpacking. It should make it more clear to do `method_name, *parms = inpt.split(); methodDict[method_name](*parms)`

Comment: @AdamSmith since poster didn't specify which python version he is using, I chose to avoid such usage of unpacking values.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to compose a function using the arguments given to the command line to the `input` prompt? You can do that using `lambda`, though in this case you seem to already have functions defined, so why worry about it?

```
def main_program(dct):
    methods = {'add': addDB,
               'find': findDB,
               'del': removeDB,
               'clear': clearAll}

    inp = input("whatever")
    method_name, *args = inp.split()
    try:
        method = methods[method_name]
    except KeyError:
        # what do you do when the user's entry is wrong?
    else:
        method(dct, *args)
```

You can also use `functools.partial` with this approach, as @ozgur did in his excellent answer

```
from functools import partial

def main_program(dct):
    methods = {'add': partial(addDB, dct),
               ...}
    # note that this is identical in effect to
    # # lambda *args: addDB(dct, *args)
    ...
    method_name, *args = inp.split()
    method = methods[method_name]  # ignoring the try/catch behavior above
    method(*args)
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly solution, but i think it's better to use `reference` than declare inside dictionary.

```
def test():
    print("it works")

dict = {"blabla" : test}
dict["blabla"]()
```